# Any way to eliminate click delays across Windows?

Tags: windows, mouse, taskbar, delay, mouse-click

Using Windows 8.1 across multiple machines and am noticing a slight timeout before my clicks register on things like balloon buttons, taskbar icons, etc. immediately after clicking on them or having them become active.

For example: if I want to bring up, say, Spotify, to replay a song that's just ended, I'll quickly click on it in the taskbar, press Enter to restart the song, and without having moved my cursor at all, click on the icon again to minimize it. But if I do this all in under maybe 3/4 of a second, the clicks on the icon to minimize it won't register until after that 3/4 of a second has elapsed. So I either have to click repeatedly until the timeout window has elapsed or wait for a bit and then click. Annoying when I end up clicking on things three or four times instead of having an immediate response.

I've noticed an identical situation when notification balloons pop up. Using the keyboard eliminates the delay--it's just a mouse input issue. I considered the mouse driver, but the window will usually flicker just a bit on the click, indicating Windows is registering the click but choosing to not do anything about it. I suspect you all may be able to replicate the issue by trying to quickly maximize and minimize any given window using the taskbar icon.

Because this issue is consistent across multiple new machines, and the delay is so consistently the same length, I doubt it's a performance issue and rather a timeout function somewhere. Does anyone have some insight as to how I might be able to shorten or eliminate this window?

Comment: Does this happen whenever you click the mouse immediately after typing or pressing a key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the double-click delay.  It exists because double-clicking as a UI action exists.  You can reduce the timeout interval, of course.  It's an ordinary Control Panel setting (under `mouse`, straightforwardly enough).  But you cannot get rid of it, and shortening the timeout has potentially undesirable side effects on other parts of the GUI.

### Further reading

- OldNewThing. 2004-10-15.  [Logical consequences of the way Windows converts single-clicks into double-clicks](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/10/15/242761.aspx).
- OldNewThing. 2008-04-23. [The double-click time tells the window manager how good your reflexes are](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/04/23/8417521.aspx).
- OldNewThing. 2008-10-12. [The dangers of setting your double-click speed too short](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/10/02/8969396.aspx).